# Date range comparison in CQ using XPATH

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr

I'm using the following query to get nodes based on last modified date in CQ.

```
/jcr:root/content/scaffoldes/properties//*[@jcr:primaryType = 'nt:unstructured' and (@sling:resourceType = 'acme/components/content/scaffoldItem' or @sling:resourceType = 'acme-core/components/data/property') and @jcr:content/cq:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000-08:00') and @jcr:content/cq:lastModified < xs:dateTime('2014-12-31T00:00:00.000-08:00') and not(@isHidden)] order by @jcr:score
```

we have used

```
  http://localhost:4502/crx/explorer/ui/search.jsp
```

To test this query. But, even after giving a huge date range (2000 - 2016) this query is returning nothing.

But If we remove the date range part, this query returns nodes.

Any pointer to correct this would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
San

**Notes**

The date string is create with the following code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(start);
String startDate = ValueFactoryImpl.getInstance().createValue(cal).getString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for any confusion caused. I found that the node which I'm trying to query doesn't have a cq:lastModified property. So modified the query to include the cq:lastReplicated in the condition.

```
 ... and ((@jcr:content/cq:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000-08:00') and @jcr:content/cq:lastModified < xs:dateTime('2016-02-11T15:52:57.090-08:00')) or (@jcr:content/cq:lastReplicated >= xs:dateTime('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000-08:00') and @jcr:content/cq:lastReplicated < xs:dateTime('2016-02-11T15:52:57.090-08:00'))) and ...
```